# Tcl/Tk: how to trigger bind function inside script instead of GUI operation

Tags: widget, tcl, bind

In my Tcl/Tk script, there is combobox widget, and I bind an event to it, if the user change the selection of  the combobox, the bind function will be triggered. 
Now I want to trigger the bind function inside script, instead of from GUI operation, how to do this? the code goes as following:

```
ttk::combobox .combo_select_tag -background white;
.combo_select_tag configure -value "1 2 3";
pack .combo_select_tag

bind .combo_select_tag <<ComboboxSelected>> {
    puts "trigger\n"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** Use [`event generate`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/event.htm#M7).

---

The `bind` command associates a binding script with an event on a binding tag. Each widget typically has four binding tags: the name of the widget, the name of the widget's class, the name of the widget's toplevel, and the `all` binding tag. (The aim is that you normally put your customizations on the individual widgets, or on the toplevel to have them apply to a whole window — which is *great* for hotkey sequences — while Tk itself focuses on the class level. The global `all` level is not used all that much but has a few backstop things.)

To activate a binding script, you need an event sent to a widget. The `event generate` command does precisely that. You can generate “real” events (like `<ButtonPress-1>` or `<KeyRelease-comma>`) or you can generate “virtual” events (like `<<ComboboxSelected>>`) and in fact *all* virtual events are generated via `event generate` (or the C API it's a thin wrapper over).

Generating a real event is a bit complicated, as they actually usually hold quite a bit of information (e.g., their location, what they're talking about, what area of the widget is invalidated, etc.) but generating a virtual event is pretty easy: you just need to know what widget it's going to and what the widget is called.

```
event generate .combo_select_tag <<ComboboxSelected>>
```

That's about it. There's a whole bunch of options you can pass (that control things like `%`-substitutions and how exactly the event is queued) but you really don't need most of them most of the time, especially for virtual events.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to trigger code specifically by generating an event, Donal Fellows' answer tells you how.

If you just want to trigger the code and don't care how, you should consider not putting the code in the `bind` script but instead in a command procedure:

```
bind .combo_select_tag <<ComboboxSelected>> comboSel

proc comboSel {} {
    puts "trigger\n"
}
```

This command can be invoked both from the script and from the gui.

Again, %-substitutions will complicate things:

```
bind .combo_select_tag <<ComboboxSelected>> {comboSel %w}

proc comboSel w {
    puts "$w: trigger\n"
}
```

the gui creates the argument automatically, but if you call this from the script you need to come up with the argument yourself.

Documentation: [bind](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/bind.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm)